# executing an UDF function in excel file from c# code

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a customized Excel User Defined Functions ([udf](/questions/tagged/udf)) that gets data from a database to the Excel Sheet.
when I execute this function (`=getData(A1,B1)`) from a c# code to get data on an excel file, it will be put on a cell without being executed until i manually open the file . here is a part of my code :

```
var rng = workSheet.Range["A2"];  //where I will put the result table
            try{

            rng.Formula = @"=getData(A1,B1)"; //A1 =Cell from where the function   will get first argument
            String formula = rng.Formula.ToString(); 
            rng.FormulaHidden = false;
            workSheet.Unprotect();
            workBook.SaveAs(filePath, AccessMode: IExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
            formula = rng.Formula;  
            bool hidden = rng.FormulaHidden;

        }
catch.....
//close opened instances of the Excel file
```

is there any solution to generate the result automatically and be prevented when the result is generated (it takes a while to get data from database)